# How to generate templates suggestion for media.html.twig for a specific field in a content type?

Tags: 8, theming

I have a content type (say Article) with an entity reference field to another content type (Author). I have used layout builder together with a view mode to display the content of the Author field in the Article content type.

One of the fields in Author is an image which is rendered via media.html.twig. Coincidentally there is also an image in Article rendered via media.html.twig

I used hook_theme_suggestions_media_alter to provide a new suggestion.

```
/**
 * Purpose: Adds theme suggestions for media.html.twig that are more specific to the content type.
 */
function custom_default_theme_suggestions_media_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $content_type = $node->bundle();
    if($content_type == 'article') {
      $suggestions[] = 'media__' . $content_type;
    }
  }

}
```

but as the Author content type is rendered on the Article  page I can't seem to get a suggestion for the Author page. Is is possible to generate a suggestion for media.html.twig for a particular field in a content type referencing another content type?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this by using the view mode along with the content type.  So the new code would be

```
/**
 * Adds theme suggestions for media.html.twig
 */
function my_custom_theme_suggestions_media_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $content_type = $node->bundle();

    // Adding suggestion for article page.
    if($content_type === 'article_page' && ($variables['elements']['#view_mode'] === 'full')) {
      $suggestions[] = 'media__' . $content_type;
    }

    // Adding suggestion for author block in article page.
    if($content_type === 'article_page' && ($variables['elements']['#view_mode'] === 'responsive_image')) {
      $suggestions[] = 'media__author_block__' . $content_type;
    }
  }
```